# Orthogonal Projectors

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Please, I need help with this proble.

> Let $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and let
>   $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_N$ closed subspaces, mutually orthogonal of $H$,
>   that is, $v_i\perp v_j$ $\forall v_i\in V_i$, $\forall v_j\in V_j$,
>   $\forall i\neq j$. Show that $$\mathbb{I} - \mathbb{P}\ =\ \mathbb{P}_1 + \mathbb{P}_2 + \ldots + \mathbb{P}_N,$$ where
>   $\mathbb{P}:H\rightarrow V_1^{\perp}\cap V_2^{\perp}\cap\ldots\cap V_N^{\perp}\;$ and $\;\mathbb{P}_j:H\rightarrow V_j$ are the orthogonal
>   projectors, respectively.

Thanx so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in H$ then we have 
$$x=\mathbb{P}_i(x)+(x-\mathbb{P}_i(x))\quad i=1,\ldots N$$
so $$x-(x-\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}_i(x))=\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}_i(x)$$

Moreover it's easy to see that
$$(\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)(\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)=(\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)$$
hence $\displaystyle (\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)$ is a projection and
$$\mathbb{P}_i(\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)=0\quad,\quad (\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)(x)=0\quad\forall x\in V_i$$
so $(\mathbb{I}-\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{P}_i)$ is the orthogonal projection onto  $ V_1^{\perp}\cap V_2^{\perp}\cap\ldots\cap V_N^{\perp}$ and parallel to $\sum_{i=1}^N V_i$

and this prove that $$\mathbb{P}(x)=(x-\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}_i(x))$$

finally we find
$$x-\mathbb{P}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}_i(x)$$